# Can't mutate/edit the column contents

Tags: dplyr, bioinformatics, rna-seq

I wrote:

```r
library(dplyr)

mutate(cell_line = gsub("cell_line: ", "" , cell_line)) %>%
  mutate(genotype_or_treatment = gsub("treatment:  ", "_" , genotype_or_treatment)) %>%
  head()
```

[image]

I was expecting the line "cell_line: " to be replaced with a space/"" in the table, but alas nothing changed. Same with "treatment: ".

Comment: Hi meeks! Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to substitute "cell_line" but the actual text in your column is "cell line". But without a reproducible example its hard to tell what is actually going on.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not a minimally reproducible one, it is hard to actually test the code I am about to propose, but it is worth a try.

```
library(tidyverse)

metadata_corrected <- metadata %>%
  mutate(cell_line = str_replace_all(cell_line, "cell_line: ", ""),
         genotype_or_treatment = str_replace_all(genotype_or_treatment, "treatment: ", ""))

metadata_corrected
```

Hope this works for you!